# Slow performance in data import when using xml in MySQL for a large recordset

Tags: c#, mysql, xml, ado.net

I am using the following code for importing of data

```
MySqlDataAdapter adaptor = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, dbSession.Connection);
MySqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new MySqlCommandBuilder(adaptor);
var insertCmd = commandBuilder.GetInsertCommand();
insertCmd.CommandTimeout = int.MaxValue;
adaptor.InsertCommand = insertCmd;

DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
dataTable.ReadXmlSchema(file);
dataTable.ReadXml(xmlfile);
adaptor.UpdateBatchSize = 1000;
adaptor.Update(dataTable);
```

I am using MySQL database. The xml file contains more than 2 million records. 
My problem is that it takes huge amount of memory and is very slow.

I can use any other format than xml if it solves above problems.

Please let me know if you need more information.

**Edit 1**:

I have tried converting the XML into a CSV file and used MySqlBulkLoader to port the data. It is amazingly fast but i am fearing that will not work in some cases where the data contains the same delimiter also, i feel that it is not a good idea to make CSV file for binary data